# How to use ScrollViewer the controls on binding?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

Following code I had. I am using a `Listbox` using binding. Below the list box I have a button for submit. Able to scroll `Listbox` items only unable to scroll the button. Button is available at the bottom of the screen(not List). I want this button at the bottom of the Listbox?.

```
 <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Height="780" MaxHeight="1800" VerticalAlignment="Top">
     <ScrollViewer.Content> 
         <Grid Grid.Row="0" >
             <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                 <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
             </Grid.RowDefinitions>
             <ListBox Name="formDetails" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Grid.Row="0" Height="780" MaxHeight="1800">
                 <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                     <DataTemplate>
                         <StackPanel Name="Text">
                             <TextBlock Name="Txt_Question" 
                                 Text="{Binding Question, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                             <TextBox Name="TxTAnswer" 
                                 Text="{Binding Stringval, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                 Visibility="{Binding DataType, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource TextConverter}}"/>
                             <CheckBox Name="BoolVal" 
                                 IsChecked="{Binding BoolVal, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                 Visibility="{Binding DataType, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource YesNoConverter}}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
            <Button  Grid.Row="1" Click="Button_Click" Content="Submit"/>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer.Content>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for button at the bottom of the Listbox:

```
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <StackPanel>
            <ListBox Name="formDetails" ItemsSource="{Binding}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Name="Text">
                            <TextBlock Name="Txt_Question" 
                         Text="{Binding Question, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                            <TextBox Name="TxTAnswer" 
                         Text="{Binding Stringval, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                         Visibility="{Binding DataType, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource TextConverter}}"/>
                            <CheckBox Name="BoolVal" 
                         IsChecked="{Binding BoolVal, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                         Visibility="{Binding DataType, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource YesNoConverter}}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
            <Button  Click="Button_Click" Content="Submit"></Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

for button at the bottom of the page

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <StackPanel>
            <ListBox Name="formDetails" ItemsSource="{Binding}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Name="Text">
                            <TextBlock Name="Txt_Question" Text="{Binding Q}"></TextBlock>
                            <TextBox Name="TxTAnswer" Text="{Binding A}"></TextBox>
                            <CheckBox Name="BoolVal" IsChecked="{Binding Val}"></CheckBox>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
    <Button  Click="Button_Click" Content="Submit" Grid.Row="1"></Button>
</Grid>
```

Comment: unable to hold the scroll at the bottom of the page. and button overrides the list elements.

Comment: Now button goes under the page :) thanks but unable to hold the scroll

Comment: Ya thanks. How to hold the scroll at the end of the page or end of the listbox?? When apply above code it's goes back to bottom and hide. Unable to user enter the values in fields which are located at the bottom of the listbox or page.

Comment: since we cant have conversation in comments so now you need to manage that from your side, i have given you idea that how you can you solve your problem. if answer has helped you please mark it as answered so it can helpful to others in future. best luck

Comment: Sorry, I am talking apart from my question. That's is another issue.

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

1. You have defined your button as being in `Grid.Row="1"` which doesn't exist. You need to add a second row otherwise it will just appear in the same row as the ListBox.
2. Your entire page is within a `ScrollViewer`, is that really what you want? If you want the Button outside of the scrollviewer then just wrap the `ListBox` within the `ScrollViewer`, but that would be kind of pointless because a `ListBox` has its own `ScrollViewer` built in.